# relationship between 'b' and 'm' sounds

Tags: history

There are several words that have a common etymological origin but are sometimes pronounced with a 'b' and sometimes with an 'm'. Here are some examples:

おもえる、おぼえる　（思える、覚える）

さむらい、さぶらい　（侍）

ぶ、む　（無）

ばく、まく　（幕）

ば　（馬）

There are many more examples. For 馬, I'm almost certain it is pronounced with an 'm' initial in every dialect of Chinese but its onyomi has a 'b'.

Is there a reason why these two similar, yet definitely distinct, consonants are related in this way?

Comment: `馬` can be pronounced with an 'm'.  One of my Japanese teacher's name is 門馬【もん・ま】（もん・ま）.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different reasons.

For native words - the historical pronunciation of Japanese voiced consonants involved prenasalisation (so /d/ was more like [ⁿd]). While in most cases the prenasalisation has been lost, in a few instances the voiced stop was the part that was dropped.

This is also the reason for the modern language's [ɡ]~[ŋ] variation.

For Sino-Japanese words - Japanese has multiple sets of on'yomi that were borrowed from Chinese at different times. The variety they were borrowed from underwent an initial denasalisation ([n]>[d]) between times when Japanese borrowed, so for example, one word which was borrowed as まく before the change was later reborrowed as ばく after the change.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that denasalisation also happens in some varieties of Min Chinese.